# python get gmail box with imaplib

Tags: python, email, imap

I can get the latest mail's subject but I want to loop to get all the mail's subjects for a specific date and I want to also get the  body.

Here's my code

```
#coding=UTF-8
import imaplib
import ConfigParser
import os
import email

#Gmail
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
username = 'XXX@gmail.com'
password = 'XXXX'
M.login(username, password)
M.select('Inbox', True)

type,data=M.search(None,'(ON 13-May-2015)')
for num in data[0].split():
    type,data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    text = data[0][1]

message = email.message_from_string(text)
def pSubject(message):
    subject = message.get('subject')  
    h = email.Header.Header(subject)
    dh = email.Header.decode_header(h)

    subject=dh[0][0]#title
    return subject

print pSubject(message) #get subject

M.close()
M.logout()
```

Comment: What's your question?